# Homebrew on OSX Mavericks: updated MongoDB to 2.4.8, start results in "error command line: unrecognized line in '/usr/local/bin/mongod'"

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I updated MongoDB using Homebrew, but now I can't start it anymore.

Console:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: test
Tue Dec 10 09:51:57.364 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

Daemon:

```
$ mongod
error command line: unrecognized line in '/usr/local/bin/mongod'
use --help for help
```

This is the content of `/usr/local/bin/mongod`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ARGV << '--config' << '/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf' unless ARGV.find { |arg|
  arg =~ /^ *--config$/ or arg =~ /^ *-f$/
}
exec "/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.8/mongod", *ARGV
```

And this is the content of `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`:

```
# Store data in /usr/local/var/mongodb instead of the default /data/db
dbpath = /usr/local/var/mongodb
/usr/local/bin/mongod

# Only accept local connections
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

The data folder exists:

```
$ ls /usr/local/var/mongodb
journal     mongod.lock
```

No idea how I can approach to fix this issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to have an extra line in your mongod.conf which just has the db path directory. Remove that and retry.

Comment: You're right, I had to remove the 3rd line (`/usr/local/bin/mongod`). Thanks.